# Не считывает строку через gets_s

Tags: c++

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct St
{
    char Name[30];
    int math;
    int phys;
    int inf;
    int chem;
    int dateOfBirth;
    int group;
    double ball;
} Students;

void addStudent() {
    f1 = fopen("list.txt", "w");
    cout << "Enter the Name of student: ";
    gets_s(Students.Name, 29);
    cout << "Enter the chemistry ball: ";
    scanf("%d", &Students.chem);                
}
```

Задача - открыть файл, считать с консоли имя студента и балл и в последствии занести это в открытый файл. Однако при выполнении не получается ввести имя, ибо сразу после "Enter the Name of student: " выводит "Enter the chemistry ball: " тем самым не позволяя ввести строку. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нострадамлю :), что где-то перед этим было что-то вроде

```
cin >> N;
```

Словом, чтение числа. После которого в буфере ввода остался `\n`, каковой и считывается в `Students.Name`...

Попробуйте перед чтением сбросить буфер, типа

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```